# Validity Dates of New Zealand Tourist Visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas, new-zealand

My New Zealand tourist visa letter says,

"The start date of your visa is: 23 August 2019
You must arrive in New Zealand before:
The number of times you may travel to New Zealand is: Single
The last date you may travel to New Zealand is: 23 December 2019
Your visa expires and you must leave New Zealand on or before: See Conditions

The Conditions of your visa: This visa expires 1 month(s) after your first arrival. Stay subject to grant of entry permission. You must leave before visa expiry or face deportation. The holder shall not undertake employment in NZ. The holder shall not study for more than 3 months in every 12 month period in NZ."

My question:
Can I enter New Zealand on 23 December 2019 and stay for 10 days? Or does my visa say that I have to leave on or before 23 December 2019.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per your letter - *The last date you may travel to New Zealand is: 23 December 2019* -  this means you need to arrive in New Zealand on or before December 23, and *This visa expires 1 month(s) after your first arrival* means you have one month after that arrival before the visa expires (and therefore need to leave the country).

So yes, you can arrive on (or before) December 23 and stay for 10 days.  But you cannot arrive on December 24 or later.

Be aware that for traveling from most countries, NZ Time is ahead, so while you may leave your origin on Dec 23, you may end up arriving on December 24!  Make sure you account for this both in travel time and time-zone adjustment.

Comment: Also take into account possible delays in your flight that may push your arrival a day further - don't plan on arriving at the last day that you are allowed to arrive.

Comment: I just called the NZ immigration officer who handled my visitor visa, and she said: "As per our phone conversation, if you travel to New Zealand on 22/Dec/2019, you must leave New Zealand on/before 22/Jan/2020."